# Align image and text in middle of container

Tags: flutter

I have a `GridView.count` which pass data of list items to a `class`. Inside the class I return a `Container` with `column>inkwell>image/text`. I want to show them in a simple layout as shown in the image attached but when I try to implement I get renderflux issues and can't seem to fix the simple task.

**The container and inside elements are code.**

```
return Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.green,
    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
      Radius.circular(8.0),
    ),
  ),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {   },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 30, 30, 30),
                  child: measureInfo.imageWidget),
              Transform.translate(
                offset: const Offset(0, 0),
                child: Text(
                  locale.translate(caption),
                  style: style,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

**Image Widget**

```
imageWidget = Image.asset(
  'Resources/Images/Measures/' + TypeHelpers.getEnumCaption(category) + '/' + caption + '.png',
  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
);
```

**Desired result and errors**
[image: Desired result]

[image: errors]

Answer (score 0):

You will use this code:

**GridView**

```
GridView.builder(
                    controller: controller.scrollController,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: controller.usersList.length,
                      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                              crossAxisCount: 2,
                              mainAxisSpacing: 16,
                              crossAxisSpacing: 16,
                              childAspectRatio: 1 / 1),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            showDialog(
                                barrierDismissible: true,
                                barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                                context: context,
                                builder: (context) {
                                  return detailDialog(
                                      controller.usersList[index]);
                                });
                          },
                          child:
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              border:
                                  Border.all(width: 2.w, color: Colors.white),
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.purple.shade100,
                                  blurRadius: 2,
                                  spreadRadius: 2,
                                  offset:
                                      const Offset(0, 0), // Shadow position
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            child: Stack(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                    width: Get.width,
                                    child: ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(10.r),
                                      child:
                                          controller.usersList[index].image !=
                                                  null
                                              ? ImageViewSquare(
                                                  image: controller
                                                      .usersList[index].image)
                                              : Image.asset(
                                                  "assets/no_pic.png",
                                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                ),
                                    )),
                                Container(
                                  height: 30,
                                  width: Get.width,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.6),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.r),
                                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.r),
                                      )),
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        controller.usersList[index].name ??
                                            "",
                                        maxLines: 1,
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 16),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      })
```

**Widget detailDialog**

```
Widget detailDialog(UserModel model) {
return Dialog(
  alignment: const Alignment(0, 0),
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
  child: Stack(children: [
    SizedBox(
      height: 270.h,
      width: MediaQuery.of(Get.context!).size.width,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 80.h,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20.r),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20.r)),
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    end: Alignment.centerRight,
                    colors: <Color>[Colors.purple, Colors.blue.shade800],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  height: 190.h,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.r),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.r)),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 32.h),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Get.toNamed(Routes.fullImage,
                        arguments: model.image as String);
                  },
                  child: Center(
                    child: ImageView(
                        color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                        image: model.image,
                        height: 90.h,
                        width: 90.w),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.h),
                  child: Text(
                    model.name ?? "",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue.shade800, fontSize: 16.sp),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.h, horizontal: 10.w),
                  child: Text(
                    model.bio ?? "",
                    maxLines: 4,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                      fontSize: 13.sp,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 10.h, left: 10.w, right: 10.w, bottom: 20.h),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        // controller.blockUser(model);
                        Get.back();
                        showDialog(
                            barrierDismissible: true,
                            barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                            context: Get.context!,
                            builder: (context) {
                              return blockUserDialogue(model);
                            });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 35.h,
                        width: 110.w,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                              blurRadius: 3,
                              spreadRadius: 3,
                              offset: const Offset(0, 0), // Shadow position
                            ),
                          ],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.r),
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Image.asset(
                              'assets/block.png',
                              width: 20.w,
                              height: 20.h,
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.w),
                              child: Text(
                                "Block",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 16.sp,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.w),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Get.back();
                          model.isFromHome=true;
                          Get.toNamed(Routes.chatScreen, arguments: model);
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          height: 35.h,
                          width: 110.w,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                                blurRadius: 3,
                                spreadRadius: 3,
                                offset:
                                    const Offset(0, 0), // Shadow position
                              ),
                            ],
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.r),
                          ),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Image.asset(
                                'assets/comment.png',
                                width: 30.w,
                                height: 30.h,
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.w),
                                child: Text(
                                  "Chat",
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 16.sp,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
  ]),
);
```

}

you will get this type of UI:

[image: User Grids]

Comment: i have tried this gridview and one other ListTile but this type ui doesn't look good.

Comment: ListTile cannot work properly. In Your case on Gridview is working. you can modified my code and change crossAxisCount: 2 to 3 and set mainAxisSpacing , crossAxisSpacing and childAspectRatio as per user need . that will definately working what you want